Document Set: list view threshold error when restoring a version
When trying to restore a Document Set, I am getting an error:

Sorry, something went wrong The attempted operation is prohibited
because it exceeds the list view threshold.



I only have approximately 10.000 documents in a Document library:

Question

Does anyone know why I am getting this error?
Is there a workaround for this issue?

Additional information
I am capturing the Document Set versions using this approach:

